# laravel broadcasting for multiple guard

Tags: php, laravel, socket.io, broadcast

I have the below auth guards that is defined for my app `admins`, `designers`, `customers` and etc. the default guard is the `designer guard`.

I want every `guard` to have his own `private channel`.
So I am defining it in my channel.php with multiple entries for each like below

```
Broadcast::channel('private.admins.{id}', function ($admin, $id) {


    Log::info($admin);
    //logging the admin

});
```

But this is always `binding` with `default guard` class so my question is how do I tell that to use here `Admin model`.
I am unable to find it anywhere. So can you point me in to right direction

Actually I want every `guard` to have his own `private channel`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try changing in `BroadcastServiceProvider` file `app\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider.php`

> Different broadcast auth end point for each guards

```
public function boot()
{
   //Broadcast::routes();
   //match any of the 3 auth guards
   Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['web','auth:admins,designers,customers']]);
   require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

> Now in channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('admins.channel.{id}', function ($model, $id) {
      return $model->id === $id && get_class($model) === 'App\Admin';
});

Broadcast::channel('designers.channel.{id}', function ($model, $id) {
      return $model->id === $id && get_class($model) === 'App\Designer';
});

Broadcast::channel('customers.channel.{id}', function ($model, $id) {
      return $model->id === $id && get_class($model) === 'App\Customer';
});
```

Comment: i adding first `Broadcast::routes([ "middleware" => ["web","auth:admin"] ]);` and for the admin guard is worked perfectly, but when i add prefix , error 404 occured into laravel-echo-server

Comment: don't add prefix, i have updated answer, you can try the second one

Comment: used this : `Broadcast::routes([ "middleware" => ["web","auth:admin, designer, customer"] ]);` and now error 500 occured by guard admin is not defined !!!!!

Comment: actually i defined the admin guard

Comment: you have to use prefix based. what is your broadcast auth url ?

Comment: @HasanTeymoori i have updated answer, you have to use different auth url in your socket connection

Comment: i don't set this:  `http://your-domain.com/broadcasting/auth/admins`, where i have set this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173702/discussion-between-rkj-and-hasan-teymoori).

Comment: @HasanTeymoori updated answer and this is tested code

Comment: Are these questions well answered? I'm facing the similar questions. I think I need to solve it by registering more routes for different guards, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: My scenario is that I have two types of guards(admin, user). I'd like to make them share the same channel, so I need two different auth routes for one single type of channels. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

I am Posting this answer, For every one who might face the problem no-days. I am using laravel 7 and `beyondcode/laravel-websockets`. As I dig in the source code specifying midllewares in BoradcastServiceProvider.php will not work. The only way to define a guard for a channel is by specifying options for the channel:

```
 Broadcast::channel('messaging.organ.{id}', function ($organ , $id) {
    return $organ->id == $id && get_class($organ) === "App\Organization";
} , ['guards' => ['organ']]);
```

**Reason**:
because I am using `beyondcode/laravel-websockets` so I dig in `src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/PusherBroadcaster.php` and in this file the `retrieveUser` method will get the user. in this file if an option for the channel is provided the user in the specified guards will be returned. you can define one or multiple guards, however it will only returns one user who is logged in as a guard that comes first in the array.

```
    protected function retrieveUser($request, $channel)
{
    $options = $this->retrieveChannelOptions($channel);

    $guards = $options['guards'] ?? null;

    if (is_null($guards)) {
        return $request->user();
    }

    foreach (Arr::wrap($guards) as $guard) {
        if ($user = $request->user($guard)) {
            return $user;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works for me, and I don't have to edit my BroadcastServiceProvider file. and if you want to use your default guards you can use the following.
['guards' => ['web', 'organ']]. And just add on into the array of any more additional guards.